# OAuth2: Why do we need redirect URI for user agent

Tags: oauth, salesforce

I recently made a small app with webserver flow. Now I am trying user-agent example. I am wondering why do we need to define a redirect-uri in user agent flow.

I am working with Saleforce.com api:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

redirect_uri    The authorization server will respond with a redirect to this URI. This parameter must match your application's configured callback URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a user agent flow, the redirect_uri is the location that the user gets redirected to after they click Approve on the approval page.  Appended onto the redirect_uri are a hash fragment, and then the access_token, instance_url, and other oauth parameters.

Comment: Thanks Willy. Are there any restrictions on what protocol, uri formats can be in a redirect_uri?

Comment: The only restriction on the redirect_uri is that its scheme cannot be http.  It must either be https or a custom scheme (like myiphoneapp://).  The second case is useful for iOS apps.  For example, you can register a custom URL scheme for your iOS app.  Then when the user clicks Approve, then your phone will open that application rather than navigate to that url in Safari.

Comment: Also for user agent flow, the value of the redirect_uri determines whether you get back a refresh_token or not.  Most of the time, a refresh token is not returned during user agent flow.  It's only returned in two situations:
1) the redirect_uri is a custom scheme
2) the redirect URL is exactly https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success, or in Sandbox, https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success  You can read the refresh_token section of https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm for more details

Comment: why will someone want to use a redirect to login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success?

Comment: A desktop client (like Salesforce for Outlook) might not have a redirect_uri to redirect their users.  So instead, their oauth flow will be contained in a popup IE window.  And as the user clicks through the oauth flow, the desktop client is listening for the window events.  And when the popup navigates to "/services/oauth2/success", they know the user is done so they grab the oauth params and close the popup.

Comment: I'm using curl to obtain access token, and i don't have a uri to call back. I have tried https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success but it gives me '500 Server Error' (and html body of a error page) since it redirects to specified uri. Used curl command as follows.
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" -d   "grant_type=password&client_id=<id>&client_secret=<secret>&username=<un>&password=<pw>" https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Appritiated any thoughts. -Thanks